# knockout using knockout amd helper - recommended folder structure

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-amd-helpers

We are using knockoutjs to develop our web application and we are using knockout-amd-helpers plugin. I have a question on the recommended folder structure.
Currently our folder structure looks like this

/app

/app/js

/app/js/viewmodels (the base directory of modules- ko.bindingHandlers.module.baseDir = "viewmodels";)

/app/js/libs (contains knockout and other library js)

/app/templates (contains all html templates ending with .tmpl.html)

/app/index.html

However there is a suggestion to restructure this folder layout by functionality where the viewmodels and template html resides in the same sub-directory of that particular functionality. For e.g.,

/app/functionality1/functionality1.tmpl.html

/app/functionality1/functionality1.js

It appears a lot of Angularjs based client side architectures uses this approach where they keep the html and js file in the same directory.

So I was wondering if there is recommended folder structure for knockoutjs based client side applications.

Comment: To me it really comes down to the size of the application. For a small to mid-sized app, having a single `viewModels` (or equivalent) directory and a single `templates` directory can work fine. Those directories can have sub-directories as necessary too.  I can see for a large application grouping by functionality. In that case you can set the template and module base directories in AMD-helpers to a common base/root. The paths specified will need to be slightly more specific in your templates and module bindings, but still manageable.

Comment: I often use the viewmodels and views breakdown - also using subdirectories to help sort the logic out.  It works a lot better for me to promote re-usable viewmodels this way but I have been doing it for about two years now so maybe I am just biased